# How to generate line chart from datatable c# winform

Tags: c#, excel, linechart

i am using Interop.Excel to export data from datatable and generate line chart too.

i could successfully export data to excel from data like this way

```
public static bool Export(System.Data.DataTable dt, string sheetName)
{
    object Missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Excel.Application oXL;
    Excel.Workbook oWB;
    Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
    Excel.Range oRange;

    try
    {
        // Start Excel and get Application object. 
        oXL = new Excel.Application();

        // Set some properties 
        oXL.Visible = false;
        oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

        // Get a new workbook. 
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing);

        // Get the Active sheet 
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
        oSheet.Name = sheetName;

        oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Daily Finished Job History " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        oSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").ColumnWidth = 13;
        oSheet.get_Range("B1", "B1").ColumnWidth = 13;
        oSheet.get_Range("C1", "C1").ColumnWidth = 25;
        oSheet.get_Range("A1", "C1").Font.Size = 14;

        oSheet.get_Range("A1", "C1").Font.Bold = true;
        oSheet.get_Range("A1", "C1").Merge(true);
        oSheet.get_Range("A1", "C1").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

        oSheet.get_Range("A3", "C3").Font.Bold = true;

        int rowCount = 3;
        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            oSheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            rowCount += 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = dr[i - 1].ToString();
            }
        }

        // Resize the columns 
        oRange = oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, 1],
        oSheet.Cells[rowCount, dt.Columns.Count]);
        //oRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

        // Save the sheet and close 
        oSheet = null;
        oRange = null;

        string strParentDirectory = GetParentDirectory();
        strParentDirectory = strParentDirectory + "\\Data";
        if (!Directory.Exists(strParentDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(strParentDirectory);
        }
        string strFileName = strParentDirectory + "\\DailyFinishedJobHistory_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xls";
        if (File.Exists(strFileName))
        {
            File.Delete(strFileName);
        }
        FileStream file = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create);
        file.Close();

        oWB.SaveAs(strFileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
            Missing, Missing, Missing, Missing,
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
            Missing, Missing, Missing,
            Missing, Missing);
        oWB.Close(Missing, Missing, Missing);
        oWB = null;
        oXL.Quit();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clean up 
        // NOTE: When in release mode, this does the trick 
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }

    return true;
}

public static string GetParentDirectory()
{
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo myDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    return myDirectory.Parent.Parent.FullName;
}
```

now i want to generate chart in same sheet based on data from my datatable.

my excel file would look like as follows
[image]

i read few article & code to generate chart from this links
http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/09/exporting-pie-chart-into-excel-file.html
http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-chart.htm
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/80834/c-and-excel-chart-ranges

but still not being able to understand the code to generate line chart. it would be great help if some help me to generate chart in same sheet like the image i have given here.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a starting point:

```
'Create & Format Chart
Dim oChart As Excel.Chart

oChart = oXL.Parent.Charts.Add
With oChart
    .Name = "History"
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Font.ColorIndex = 11
    .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
    .ChartTitle.Font.Size = 12
    .ChartTitle.Font.Name = "Arial"
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Job History"
    .ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLine
    .HasLegend = True
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$4:$A$6"
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$B$3"
    .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Sheet1!$C$3"
    .SeriesCollection(3).Name = "=Sheet1!$D$3"
End With
```